# Check if my app can show notification

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

In Android 5, aka Lollipop, how can I check if my app can show notification? (By using SDK)

I want to warn user if system blocked my notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a notification and then query [NotificationListenerService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#getActiveNotifications%28%29) whether the notification was displayed. The returned [StatusBarNotification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/StatusBarNotification.html) should contain enough metadata for you to identify your notification.